# Laplace transform using change of scale property

Tags: laplace-transform

If Laplace transform of $f(t)=\phi(s)$, then Laplace transform of $e^{bt}f(at)$ is

Comment: You probably don't mean to use the same $a$ in $\phi(a)$ and $f(at)$.

Comment: Sorry for the error, edited now.

Answer (score 1):

You are given:
$$
\int_{t=0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}\;dt=\phi (s)
$$
and are asked for:
$$
\int_{t=0}^{\infty} e^{bt}f(at)e^{-st}\;dt=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} f(at)e^{-(s-b)t}\;dt
$$
Now put $t'=at$ when the integral becomes:
$$
\int_{t=0}^{\infty} e^{bt}f(at)e^{-st}\;dt=\int_{t'=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}f(t')e^{-\frac{s-b}{a}t'}\;dt'=\frac{1}{a}\phi\left(\frac{s-b}{a}\right)
$$